# how to remove url in address bar after slash using location.pathname.substring(1)

Tags: javascript

I have http://www.example.com/page/3/.

Now I want to remove "/page/3/" using javascript.

When I google for solution I found "location.pathname.substring(1)" but don't know how I will implement it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try Using this.

```
var addressValue = document.location.pathname.substring(1);
var addressParts = addressValue.split(/\//);
var result = addressParts[0];
alert(result);
```